# Does there exist the concept of set-once variables?

Tags: theory, solid-principles

I am wondering if anyone has developed the concept of a set-once variable.  That is, a variable that perhaps has some default value, but can be set only once during program execution.  Note this differs from any kind of constant, as constants are set before program execution.

Comment: Constants are not necessarily set before program execution. But please pick one language.

Comment: if you're setting it during runtime, then it's a variable. there isn't any way around it. at least in c++ you could wrap it in an object with appropriate protections and setters/getters that enforce the one-time-only business.

Comment: There's no native "set-once" type in C or C++, but since they are Turing-complete languages you can implement the concept easily enough.

Comment: Solution looking for a problem.

Comment: Both C and C++ can have `const`s that have runtime value. The value doesn't have to be known until declaration. All `const` inputs of function works this way. In C++ you can even have `const` members that can be initialized to dynamic values in constructors.

Comment: I think Haskell has set-once variables.

Comment: @user3528438 it was requested that the variable has a default value (which presumably may be read for some period leading up to when the single write is made)

Comment: You might be interested in Go's [sync.Once](http://golang.org/pkg/sync#Once) which implements actions that will be performed exactly once.

Comment: final variables do that in java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no prepackaged solution for this, but since we have [`once_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag) now, we could write an overkill solution that guarantees that you can only call `operator=` once:

```
template <typename T>
class SetOnce
{
public:
    SetOnce(T const& v)
    : val(v)
    { }

    SetOnce& operator=(T const& v) {
        std::call_once(flag, [=]{
            val = v;
        });
        return *this;
    }

    T get() const { return val; }

private:
    std::once_flag flag;
    T val;
};

int main() {
    SetOnce<int> so(4);
    std::cout << so.get() << '\n'; // 4
    so = 5;
    std::cout << so.get() << '\n'; // 5
    so = 6;
    std::cout << so.get() << '\n'; // still 5
}
```

Not sure what you'd do with such a thing, but C++11 sure is cool.

Comment: OK, that's pretty cool.  FWIW, this is not a solution looking for a problem.

Answer (score 1):

No such construct exists natively in C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

Well a C++ reference kind of does this.

A reference variable, e.g. `T & ref`, can only be bound once (but at run-time, to anything). After that, the pointer expression `&ref` is effectively a constant, and the language rules do not permit it to change.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a pair of functions can be used to effect a *set-once variable*.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define set_once_default 7
typedef struct set_once_S set_once_T;

set_once_T *value = NULL;

int set_once_read(set_once_T *ptr) {
  if (ptr == NULL) return set_once_default;
  return *((int *) ptr);
}

void set_once_write(set_once_T *ptr, int value) {
  if (ptr == NULL) {
    ptr = malloc(sizeof value);
    assert(ptr);
    *((int *) ptr) = value;
  }
}
```

Should a non-global `set_once_T` be needed, code would need to `free()` it as it goes out of scope.